# What is the right order of linker flags in gcc?

Tags: gcc, linker

Normally, I would compile a program that requires a specific library, e.g. math, by passing the linker flag after the sources that need it like so:

```
gcc foo.c -lm
```

However, it seems that older versions of gcc work equally well with the reverse order (let's call this *BAD ORDER*):

```
gcc -lm foo.c
```

I wouldn't worry about it if some popular open-source projects I'm trying to compile didn't use the latter while my version of `gcc` (or is it `ld` that's the problem?) work only in the former case (also, the correct one in my opinion).

My question is: when did the *BAD ORDER* stop working and why? It seems that not supporting it breaks legacy packages.

Comment: Not exactly sure but I think pre-GCC 4.5. Long ago. Subsequently, the `--as-needed` option is operative for shared libraries by default, so like static libraries, they must occur in the linkage sequence later than the
objects for which they provide definitions. The change is in the default options that the `gcc/g++/gfrotran/etc.` tool-driver passes to `ld`.

Comment: Thanks, I tried to find out the answer to "why" before I replied to your comment, but didn't reach anything conclusive.

Comment: Neither have I but it was to regularize what was felt to be a confusing discrepancy between linkage of static libraries and shared libraries.

Comment: Correction: Meant "I think it was"

Comment: Sounds reasonable. If you create an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> when did the BAD ORDER stop working and why? It seems that not supporting it breaks legacy packages.

**When?**

Not dead sure but I think pre-GCC 4.5. Long ago. Subsequently, the `--as-needed` option is operative for shared libraries by default, 
so like static libraries, they must occur in the linkage sequence later than the objects for which they provide definitions. 
This is a change in the default options that the `gcc/g++/gfortran` etc. tool-driver passes to `ld`.

**Why?**

It was considered confusing to inexpert users that static libraries by default has to appear
later that the objects to which they provided definitions while shared libraries by default did
not - the difference between the two typically being concealed by the `-l<name>` convention
for linking either `libname.a` or `libname.so`.

It was perhaps an unforeseen consequence that inexpert users who
had formerly had a lot of luck with the mistaken belief that a GCC
[compile and] link command conforms to the normal Unix pattern:

```
command [OPTION...] FILE [FILE...]
```

e.g.

```
gcc -lthis -lthat -o prog foo.o bar.o
```

now fare much worse with it.