# Find the Linking error in this Makefile

Tags: c++, makefile, wxwidgets, linker-errors

I'm trying to compile [this](http://nghiaho.com/?page_id=227) piece of software called Register3D_wx but have problems when trying to run make. I have installed Open GSL, Open GL and wxWidgets library as required. When I cd into the folder and run make, I get lots of error messages. I'm giving some of the output:

```
james@james-HP-Z420-Workstation:~/Downloads/Register3D_wx_1.1.1$ sudo make 
test -d bin/Release || mkdir -p bin/Release
test -d obj/Release/ann_1.1.2/src || mkdir -p obj/Release/ann_1.1.2/src
test -d obj/Release/ || mkdir -p obj/Release/
g++  -O2 -Wall `wx-config --cflags` `gsl-config --cflags` -Iann_1.1.2/include -c ann_1.1.2/src/kd_pr_search.cpp -o obj/Release/ann_1.1.2/src/kd_pr_search.o
gcc  -O2 -Wall `wx-config --cflags` `gsl-config --cflags` -Iann_1.1.2/include -c ZPR.cc -o obj/Release/ZPR.o
ZPR.cc: In member function ‘void ZPR::ZprPick(GLdouble, GLdouble, GLdouble, GLdouble)’:
ZPR.cc:424:26: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
          if (buffer[j+1]<minZ)
                          ^
ZPR.cc:380:11: warning: variable ‘min’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
    GLint  min  = -1;
           ^
g++  -O2 -Wall `wx-config --cflags` `gsl-config --cflags` -Iann_1.1.2/include -c ann_1.1.2/src/ANN.cpp -o obj/Release/ann_1.1.2/src/ANN.o
g++  -O2 -Wall `wx-config --cflags` `gsl-config --cflags` -Iann_1.1.2/include -c ann_1.1.2/src/bd_fix_rad_search.cpp -o obj/Release/ann_1.1.2/src/bd_fix_rad_search.o
g++  -O2 -Wall `wx-config --cflags` `gsl-config --cflags` -Iann_1.1.2/include -c ann_1.1.2/src/bd_pr_search.cpp -o obj/Release/ann_1.1.2/src/bd_pr_search.o
g++  -O2 -Wall `wx-config --cflags` `gsl-config --cflags` -Iann_1.1.2/include -c ann_1.1.2/src/bd_search.cpp -o obj/Release/ann_1.1.2/src/bd_search.o
g++  -O2 -Wall `wx-config --cflags` `gsl-config --cflags` -Iann_1.1.2/include -c ann_1.1.2/src/bd_tree.cpp -o obj/Release/ann_1.1.2/src/bd_tree.o
g++  -O2 -Wall `wx-config --cflags` `gsl-config --cflags` -Iann_1.1.2/include -c ann_1.1.2/src/brute.cpp -o obj/Release/ann_1.1.2/src/brute.o
g++  -O2 -Wall `wx-config --cflags` `gsl-config --cflags` -Iann_1.1.2/include -c ann_1.1.2/src/kd_dump.cpp -o obj/Release/ann_1.1.2/src/kd_dump.o
g++  -O2 -Wall `wx-config --cflags` `gsl-config --cflags` -Iann_1.1.2/include -c ann_1.1.2/src/kd_fix_rad_search.cpp -o obj/Release/ann_1.1.2/src/kd_fix_rad_search.o
gcc  -O2 -Wall `wx-config --cflags` `gsl-config --cflags` -Iann_1.1.2/include -c PointOP.cc -o obj/Release/PointOP.o
g++  -O2 -Wall `wx-config --cflags` `gsl-config --cflags` -Iann_1.1.2/include -c ann_1.1.2/src/kd_search.cpp -o obj/Release/ann_1.1.2/src/kd_search.o
g++  -O2 -Wall `wx-config --cflags` `gsl-config --cflags` -Iann_1.1.2/include -c ann_1.1.2/src/kd_split.cpp -o obj/Release/ann_1.1.2/src/kd_split.o
g++  -O2 -Wall `wx-config --cflags` `gsl-config --cflags` -Iann_1.1.2/include -c ann_1.1.2/src/kd_tree.cpp -o obj/Release/ann_1.1.2/src/kd_tree.o
g++  -O2 -Wall `wx-config --cflags` `gsl-config --cflags` -Iann_1.1.2/include -c ann_1.1.2/src/kd_util.cpp -o obj/Release/ann_1.1.2/src/kd_util.o
g++  -O2 -Wall `wx-config --cflags` `gsl-config --cflags` -Iann_1.1.2/include -c ann_1.1.2/src/perf.cpp -o obj/Release/ann_1.1.2/src/perf.o
gcc  -O2 -Wall `wx-config --cflags` `gsl-config --cflags` -Iann_1.1.2/include -c main.cc -o obj/Release/main.o
gcc  -O2 -Wall `wx-config --cflags` `gsl-config --cflags` -Iann_1.1.2/include -c MainWindow.cc -o obj/Release/MainWindow.o
gcc  -O2 -Wall `wx-config --cflags` `gsl-config --cflags` -Iann_1.1.2/include -c Cylinder.cc -o obj/Release/Cylinder.o
gcc  -O2 -Wall `wx-config --cflags` `gsl-config --cflags` -Iann_1.1.2/include -c GLCanvas.cc -o obj/Release/GLCanvas.o
gcc  -O2 -Wall `wx-config --cflags` `gsl-config --cflags` -Iann_1.1.2/include -c Help.cc -o obj/Release/Help.o
gcc  -O2 -Wall `wx-config --cflags` `gsl-config --cflags` -Iann_1.1.2/include -c ICP.cc -o obj/Release/ICP.o
ICP.cc: In member function ‘void ICP::SetPoints(std::vector<Point>&, std::vector<Point>&, float)’:
ICP.cc:439:73: warning: format ‘%i’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘std::vector<Point>::size_type {aka long unsigned int}’ [-Wformat=]
     printf("Number of points after downsampling: %i\n", m_points2.size());
                                                                         ^
gcc  -O2 -Wall `wx-config --cflags` `gsl-config --cflags` -Iann_1.1.2/include -c ICPDialog.cc -o obj/Release/ICPDialog.o
gcc  -O2 -Wall `wx-config --cflags` `gsl-config --cflags` -Iann_1.1.2/include -c About.cc -o obj/Release/About.o
gcc  -O2 -Wall `wx-config --cflags` `gsl-config --cflags` -Iann_1.1.2/include -c Math2.cc -o obj/Release/Math2.o
gcc  -O2 -Wall `wx-config --cflags` `gsl-config --cflags` -Iann_1.1.2/include -c Matrix.cc -o obj/Release/Matrix.o
gcc  -O2 -Wall `wx-config --cflags` `gsl-config --cflags` -Iann_1.1.2/include -c Misc.cc -o obj/Release/Misc.o
gcc  -O2 -Wall `wx-config --cflags` `gsl-config --cflags` -Iann_1.1.2/include -c MyANN.cc -o obj/Release/MyANN.o
gcc  -O2 -Wall `wx-config --cflags` `gsl-config --cflags` -Iann_1.1.2/include -c OGLWrapper.cc -o obj/Release/OGLWrapper.o
gcc  -O2 -Wall `wx-config --cflags` `gsl-config --cflags` -Iann_1.1.2/include -c Point.cc -o obj/Release/Point.o
g++  -s `wx-config --libs` `wx-config --libs gl` `gsl-config --libs` -Lann_1.1.2/include obj/Release/ann_1.1.2/src/kd_pr_search.o obj/Release/ZPR.o obj/Release/ann_1.1.2/src/ANN.o obj/Release/ann_1.1.2/src/bd_fix_rad_search.o obj/Release/ann_1.1.2/src/bd_pr_search.o obj/Release/ann_1.1.2/src/bd_search.o obj/Release/ann_1.1.2/src/bd_tree.o obj/Release/ann_1.1.2/src/brute.o obj/Release/ann_1.1.2/src/kd_dump.o obj/Release/ann_1.1.2/src/kd_fix_rad_search.o obj/Release/PointOP.o obj/Release/ann_1.1.2/src/kd_search.o obj/Release/ann_1.1.2/src/kd_split.o obj/Release/ann_1.1.2/src/kd_tree.o obj/Release/ann_1.1.2/src/kd_util.o obj/Release/ann_1.1.2/src/perf.o obj/Release/main.o obj/Release/MainWindow.o obj/Release/Cylinder.o obj/Release/GLCanvas.o obj/Release/Help.o obj/Release/ICP.o obj/Release/ICPDialog.o obj/Release/About.o obj/Release/Math2.o obj/Release/Matrix.o obj/Release/Misc.o obj/Release/MyANN.o obj/Release/OGLWrapper.o obj/Release/Point.o  -lz -lGLEW -lGL -lglut -o bin/Release/Register3D_wx
obj/Release/ICP.o: In function `ICP::SetPoints(std::vector<Point, std::allocator<Point> >&, std::vector<Point, std::allocator<Point> >&, float)':
ICP.cc:(.text+0x38c): undefined reference to `wxStringBase::npos'
ICP.cc:(.text+0x3a4): undefined reference to `wxStringBase::InitWith(wchar_t const*, unsigned long, unsigned long)'
ICP.cc:(.text+0x49a): undefined reference to `wxString::Format(wchar_t const*, ...)'
ICP.cc:(.text+0x593): undefined reference to `wxStringBase::npos'
ICP.cc:(.text+0x5ab): undefined reference to `wxStringBase::InitWith(wchar_t const*, unsigned long, unsigned long)'
ICP.cc:(.text+0x614): undefined reference to `wxString::Format(wchar_t const*, ...)'
ICP.cc:(.text+0x6d9): undefined reference to `wxStringBase::npos'
ICP.cc:(.text+0x6f1): undefined reference to `wxStringBase::InitWith(wchar_t const*, unsigned long, unsigned long)'
ICP.cc:(.text+0x7da): undefined reference to `wxString::Format(wchar_t const*, ...)'
```

I know I need to edit the Makefile but that's where I am stuck. I do have some experience with makesfiles but don't know what to do. Moreover, all the dependencies are are complied and the object files produced so I don't know why ICP.cc is having this undefined reference error. The makefile is:

```
    #------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
# This makefile was generated by 'cbp2make' tool rev.107                       #
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------#


WRKDIR = `pwd`

CC = gcc
CXX = g++
AR = ar
LD = g++
WINDRES = windres

INC =  -Iann_1.1.2/include
CFLAGS = 
RESINC = 
LIBDIR =  -Lann_1.1.2/include
LIB = 
LDFLAGS = 

INC_RELEASE =  $(INC)
CFLAGS_RELEASE =  $(CFLAGS) -O2 -Wall `wx-config --cflags` `gsl-config --cflags`
RESINC_RELEASE =  $(RESINC)
RCFLAGS_RELEASE =  $(RCFLAGS)
LIBDIR_RELEASE =  $(LIBDIR)
LIB_RELEASE = $(LIB) -lz -lGLEW -lGL -lglut
LDFLAGS_RELEASE =  $(LDFLAGS) -s `wx-config --libs` `wx-config --libs gl` `gsl-config --libs`
OBJDIR_RELEASE = obj/Release
DEP_RELEASE = 
OUT_RELEASE = bin/Release/Register3D_wx

OBJ_RELEASE = $(OBJDIR_RELEASE)/ann_1.1.2/src/kd_pr_search.o $(OBJDIR_RELEASE)/ZPR.o $(OBJDIR_RELEASE)/ann_1.1.2/src/ANN.o $(OBJDIR_RELEASE)/ann_1.1.2/src/bd_fix_rad_search.o $(OBJDIR_RELEASE)/ann_1.1.2/src/bd_pr_search.o $(OBJDIR_RELEASE)/ann_1.1.2/src/bd_search.o $(OBJDIR_RELEASE)/ann_1.1.2/src/bd_tree.o $(OBJDIR_RELEASE)/ann_1.1.2/src/brute.o $(OBJDIR_RELEASE)/ann_1.1.2/src/kd_dump.o $(OBJDIR_RELEASE)/ann_1.1.2/src/kd_fix_rad_search.o $(OBJDIR_RELEASE)/PointOP.o $(OBJDIR_RELEASE)/ann_1.1.2/src/kd_search.o $(OBJDIR_RELEASE)/ann_1.1.2/src/kd_split.o $(OBJDIR_RELEASE)/ann_1.1.2/src/kd_tree.o $(OBJDIR_RELEASE)/ann_1.1.2/src/kd_util.o $(OBJDIR_RELEASE)/ann_1.1.2/src/perf.o $(OBJDIR_RELEASE)/main.o $(OBJDIR_RELEASE)/MainWindow.o $(OBJDIR_RELEASE)/Cylinder.o $(OBJDIR_RELEASE)/GLCanvas.o $(OBJDIR_RELEASE)/Help.o $(OBJDIR_RELEASE)/ICP.o $(OBJDIR_RELEASE)/ICPDialog.o $(OBJDIR_RELEASE)/About.o $(OBJDIR_RELEASE)/Math2.o $(OBJDIR_RELEASE)/Matrix.o $(OBJDIR_RELEASE)/Misc.o $(OBJDIR_RELEASE)/MyANN.o $(OBJDIR_RELEASE)/OGLWrapper.o $(OBJDIR_RELEASE)/Point.o

all: Release

clean: clean_Release

before_Release: 
    test -d bin/Release || mkdir -p bin/Release
    test -d $(OBJDIR_RELEASE)/ann_1.1.2/src || mkdir -p $(OBJDIR_RELEASE)/ann_1.1.2/src
    test -d $(OBJDIR_RELEASE)/ || mkdir -p $(OBJDIR_RELEASE)/

after_Release: 

Release: before_Release out_Release after_Release

out_Release: $(OBJ_RELEASE) $(DEP_RELEASE)
    $(LD) $(LDFLAGS_RELEASE) $(LIBDIR_RELEASE) $(OBJ_RELEASE) $(LIB_RELEASE) -o $(OUT_RELEASE)

$(OBJDIR_RELEASE)/ann_1.1.2/src/kd_pr_search.o: ann_1.1.2/src/kd_pr_search.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CFLAGS_RELEASE) $(INC_RELEASE) -c ann_1.1.2/src/kd_pr_search.cpp -o $(OBJDIR_RELEASE)/ann_1.1.2/src/kd_pr_search.o

$(OBJDIR_RELEASE)/ZPR.o: ZPR.cc
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS_RELEASE) $(INC_RELEASE) -c ZPR.cc -o $(OBJDIR_RELEASE)/ZPR.o

$(OBJDIR_RELEASE)/ann_1.1.2/src/ANN.o: ann_1.1.2/src/ANN.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CFLAGS_RELEASE) $(INC_RELEASE) -c ann_1.1.2/src/ANN.cpp -o $(OBJDIR_RELEASE)/ann_1.1.2/src/ANN.o

$(OBJDIR_RELEASE)/ann_1.1.2/src/bd_fix_rad_search.o: ann_1.1.2/src/bd_fix_rad_search.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CFLAGS_RELEASE) $(INC_RELEASE) -c ann_1.1.2/src/bd_fix_rad_search.cpp -o $(OBJDIR_RELEASE)/ann_1.1.2/src/bd_fix_rad_search.o

$(OBJDIR_RELEASE)/ann_1.1.2/src/bd_pr_search.o: ann_1.1.2/src/bd_pr_search.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CFLAGS_RELEASE) $(INC_RELEASE) -c ann_1.1.2/src/bd_pr_search.cpp -o $(OBJDIR_RELEASE)/ann_1.1.2/src/bd_pr_search.o

$(OBJDIR_RELEASE)/ann_1.1.2/src/bd_search.o: ann_1.1.2/src/bd_search.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CFLAGS_RELEASE) $(INC_RELEASE) -c ann_1.1.2/src/bd_search.cpp -o $(OBJDIR_RELEASE)/ann_1.1.2/src/bd_search.o

$(OBJDIR_RELEASE)/ann_1.1.2/src/bd_tree.o: ann_1.1.2/src/bd_tree.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CFLAGS_RELEASE) $(INC_RELEASE) -c ann_1.1.2/src/bd_tree.cpp -o $(OBJDIR_RELEASE)/ann_1.1.2/src/bd_tree.o

$(OBJDIR_RELEASE)/ann_1.1.2/src/brute.o: ann_1.1.2/src/brute.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CFLAGS_RELEASE) $(INC_RELEASE) -c ann_1.1.2/src/brute.cpp -o $(OBJDIR_RELEASE)/ann_1.1.2/src/brute.o

$(OBJDIR_RELEASE)/ann_1.1.2/src/kd_dump.o: ann_1.1.2/src/kd_dump.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CFLAGS_RELEASE) $(INC_RELEASE) -c ann_1.1.2/src/kd_dump.cpp -o $(OBJDIR_RELEASE)/ann_1.1.2/src/kd_dump.o

$(OBJDIR_RELEASE)/ann_1.1.2/src/kd_fix_rad_search.o: ann_1.1.2/src/kd_fix_rad_search.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CFLAGS_RELEASE) $(INC_RELEASE) -c ann_1.1.2/src/kd_fix_rad_search.cpp -o $(OBJDIR_RELEASE)/ann_1.1.2/src/kd_fix_rad_search.o

$(OBJDIR_RELEASE)/PointOP.o: PointOP.cc
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS_RELEASE) $(INC_RELEASE) -c PointOP.cc -o $(OBJDIR_RELEASE)/PointOP.o

$(OBJDIR_RELEASE)/ann_1.1.2/src/kd_search.o: ann_1.1.2/src/kd_search.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CFLAGS_RELEASE) $(INC_RELEASE) -c ann_1.1.2/src/kd_search.cpp -o $(OBJDIR_RELEASE)/ann_1.1.2/src/kd_search.o

$(OBJDIR_RELEASE)/ann_1.1.2/src/kd_split.o: ann_1.1.2/src/kd_split.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CFLAGS_RELEASE) $(INC_RELEASE) -c ann_1.1.2/src/kd_split.cpp -o $(OBJDIR_RELEASE)/ann_1.1.2/src/kd_split.o

$(OBJDIR_RELEASE)/ann_1.1.2/src/kd_tree.o: ann_1.1.2/src/kd_tree.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CFLAGS_RELEASE) $(INC_RELEASE) -c ann_1.1.2/src/kd_tree.cpp -o $(OBJDIR_RELEASE)/ann_1.1.2/src/kd_tree.o

$(OBJDIR_RELEASE)/ann_1.1.2/src/kd_util.o: ann_1.1.2/src/kd_util.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CFLAGS_RELEASE) $(INC_RELEASE) -c ann_1.1.2/src/kd_util.cpp -o $(OBJDIR_RELEASE)/ann_1.1.2/src/kd_util.o

$(OBJDIR_RELEASE)/ann_1.1.2/src/perf.o: ann_1.1.2/src/perf.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CFLAGS_RELEASE) $(INC_RELEASE) -c ann_1.1.2/src/perf.cpp -o $(OBJDIR_RELEASE)/ann_1.1.2/src/perf.o

$(OBJDIR_RELEASE)/main.o: main.cc
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS_RELEASE) $(INC_RELEASE) -c main.cc -o $(OBJDIR_RELEASE)/main.o

$(OBJDIR_RELEASE)/MainWindow.o: MainWindow.cc
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS_RELEASE) $(INC_RELEASE) -c MainWindow.cc -o $(OBJDIR_RELEASE)/MainWindow.o

$(OBJDIR_RELEASE)/Cylinder.o: Cylinder.cc
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS_RELEASE) $(INC_RELEASE) -c Cylinder.cc -o $(OBJDIR_RELEASE)/Cylinder.o

$(OBJDIR_RELEASE)/GLCanvas.o: GLCanvas.cc
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS_RELEASE) $(INC_RELEASE) -c GLCanvas.cc -o $(OBJDIR_RELEASE)/GLCanvas.o

$(OBJDIR_RELEASE)/Help.o: Help.cc
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS_RELEASE) $(INC_RELEASE) -c Help.cc -o $(OBJDIR_RELEASE)/Help.o

$(OBJDIR_RELEASE)/ICP.o: ICP.cc
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS_RELEASE) $(INC_RELEASE) -c ICP.cc -o $(OBJDIR_RELEASE)/ICP.o

$(OBJDIR_RELEASE)/ICPDialog.o: ICPDialog.cc
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS_RELEASE) $(INC_RELEASE) -c ICPDialog.cc -o $(OBJDIR_RELEASE)/ICPDialog.o

$(OBJDIR_RELEASE)/About.o: About.cc
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS_RELEASE) $(INC_RELEASE) -c About.cc -o $(OBJDIR_RELEASE)/About.o

$(OBJDIR_RELEASE)/Math2.o: Math2.cc
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS_RELEASE) $(INC_RELEASE) -c Math2.cc -o $(OBJDIR_RELEASE)/Math2.o

$(OBJDIR_RELEASE)/Matrix.o: Matrix.cc
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS_RELEASE) $(INC_RELEASE) -c Matrix.cc -o $(OBJDIR_RELEASE)/Matrix.o

$(OBJDIR_RELEASE)/Misc.o: Misc.cc
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS_RELEASE) $(INC_RELEASE) -c Misc.cc -o $(OBJDIR_RELEASE)/Misc.o

$(OBJDIR_RELEASE)/MyANN.o: MyANN.cc
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS_RELEASE) $(INC_RELEASE) -c MyANN.cc -o $(OBJDIR_RELEASE)/MyANN.o

$(OBJDIR_RELEASE)/OGLWrapper.o: OGLWrapper.cc
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS_RELEASE) $(INC_RELEASE) -c OGLWrapper.cc -o $(OBJDIR_RELEASE)/OGLWrapper.o

$(OBJDIR_RELEASE)/Point.o: Point.cc
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS_RELEASE) $(INC_RELEASE) -c Point.cc -o $(OBJDIR_RELEASE)/Point.o

clean_Release: 
    rm -f $(OBJ_RELEASE) $(OUT_RELEASE)
    rm -rf $(OBJDIR_RELEASE)/ann_1.1.2/src
    rm -rf $(OBJDIR_RELEASE)/

.PHONY: before_Release after_Release clean_Release
```

Comment: I am aware of the general causes of linking error but this is a very specific example do please consider this as not being a duplicate of those general questions

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does the order of '-l' option in gcc matter?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11893996/why-does-the-order-of-l-option-in-gcc-matter)

Comment: Useless and dangerous use of `sudo`.

Answer (score 0):

I see two potential problems here:

1. You should use `wx-config --libs std,gl` to link with all normal wxWidgets libraries *and* wxWidgets OpenGL library instead of just the latter.
2. You should ensure that in your link command `LDFLAGS_RELEASE` comes *after* the object files, this is important if you're using static wxWidgets libraries.

Comment: Re. 2 On Debian-based distros all libraries, not just static ones, by default must appear after the object files that need symbols from them.

Comment: @MikeKinghan Interesting, I didn't know this. Would you have any links explaining when has this changed and why? TIA!

Comment: Hi. See [What is the right order of linker flags in gcc?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35897290/1362568)
and answer. Although that discussion wasn't explicitly restricted to Debian-based distros, it should have been. Fedora, for instance, hasn't changed.

Comment: @VZ I did both 1 and 2. Now I have these errors: /usr/bin/ld: obj/Release/GLCanvas.o: undefined reference to symbol 'glDepthFunc'
//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [out_Release] Error 1

Comment: You probably have the same problem with the order of `-lGL`, it must come _after_ the library using it (which is inside `wx-config --libs gl` output).